# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Intellij 14 with ANTLR4 plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

I've installed the ANTLR4 plugin for Intellij, but cannot work with grammar files.

Upon the IDE start I immediately get:

```
NoClassDefFoundError:
org.antlr.intellij.plugin.ANTLRv4PluginController@109bb62:
org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/gui/TreeViewer
```

Then, when I double click on a grammar file I get:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer
```

Seems like IDE does not know where to pick the ANTLR jar file.

My project does have a dependency on `antlr-4.5-complete.jar`.

Are there some addition configuration steps I need to perform in order to let the IDE know where to look for the proper jar?

Comment: ANTLR 4.5 is baked into the plugin. Are you trying to build or just edit a grammar?  Very odd. Windows? Linux? Mac? Which java.

Comment: Windows 7, x64. Happens with both Java 1.7 and 1.8. I'm just trying to get started with grammars - no Java coding yet. G4 file appears greyed out, so I cannot even open it inside the IDE. BTW, what do you mean by "embedded"? In the installation folder I see 2 files - plugin.jar and antlr-4.5-complete.jar. The first is too small to embed the second inside it.

Comment: it must have unzipped those or something during installation. if you look, the plug-in itself contains all of that. Someone in my class with a Linux install seem to have something similar. Another student explain something about the preferences that I didn't get but I don't have to do anything on my Mac. can you try intellij 13 quickly?

Comment: OMG... I've unzipped the intellij-plugin-v4.zip and pointed the IDE directly to the plugin.jar...
Re-installed using the zip file. Now it works!
Thanks and sorry!

Comment: I've done the same thing, this has saved me from pulling my hair out:)

Answer (score 4):

Hooray! Ok, so then the answer to this question is to ask intellij to install the plug-in. Or you can download intellij-plugin-v4.zip, but don't unzip it.